# Android listview entire list getting selected

Tags: android, listview

I  seem to be having a UI problem with a listview. I have a listview and selecting any item on the list, highlights the entire listview. The selection is working fine, I get the correct item in the listener.

But the problem is that when i select any item, the entire listview gets highlighted, so it is difficult to tell which row got selected.

This is working fine on Android >3.1 - Currently i am testing on a 2.3 device.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:listSelector="#99000000"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed this by removing this line: (not sure why it worked)

android:listSelector="#99000000"

Answer (score 26):

I recently had the same issue, but the reason was in Android < 3.0 bug: if you set a @color as a drawable for your list item pressed selector, then it will fill the entire list area. Solution is to use a 'shape' drawable instead of @color.

So, create a new XML file in `res/drawable` folder with similar content:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/my_list_item_pressed_color" />
</shape>
```

And reference created drawable in your `ListView` selector for `state_pressed` (also created as an XML file in `res/drawable` folder):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed_bg" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And use this selector in your `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    .....
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector" />
```

That's all. Works at least with Android 2.2-2.3.

Comment: Thanks! These pre 3.0/4.0 bug are really annoying, because they are not documented at all!

Comment: Wish I found this post hours before. Note, you can do it programatically as well: `ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape()); sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED); listview.setSelector(sd);`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your selector, you can also set it as the background of the list item's layout, rather than in the listSelector field of the ListView.  The list items receive the "selected" state when touched and the color is displayed properly.

This works for all versions of Android.

Ex: This is your list item layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_color">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your text here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And your list with no list selector:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```